# What does 1..self mean in this ruby code?

Tags: ruby

I can't seem to figure out what the 1..self means in this code..more specifically I can't figure out what self returns in this scope? ( I know what 1...10 means for example

```
class Fixnum 
  def palindrome_below i
    (1...self).select{|f| f.to_s(i) == f.to_s(i).reverse}
  end  
end
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Print `self`... Question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `palindrome_below` definition is an *instance method* on `Fixnum`. An instance method is a function that can be called on *an instance of a class* (in contrast to a class method, which is called on the class itself).

Given this code, any instance of `Fixnum` will have access to `palindrome_below` method wherein`self` refers to the `Fixnum` instance *itself* (and `i` refers to the argument being passed to the method call).

```
14.palindrome_below(5)
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12] # `self` refers to the Fixnum `14`
```

Consequently, the output below is identical to the example above:

```
(1...14).select{|f| f.to_s(5) == f.to_s(5).reverse}
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

`x...y` creates a [`Range`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Range.html) with the interval `(x, y]`. In your context, `self` is referring to an instance of `Fixnum`.

Any integer that can be represented in one native machine word is an instance of `Fixnum`. Here is a simple example:

```
class Fixnum
  def double
    self * 2
  end
end

# self is `2`
2.double # => 4

# self is `8`
8.double # => 16
```